# Merge the "hadoop" and "apache-hadoop" tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

These tags refer to exactly the same project, one is just prefixed with apache.

[apache-hadoop](/questions/tagged/apache-hadoop) was created on Dec 26th by Community for some reason, so I am proposing to merge it with [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop) which is much older. It doesn't make sense to have both, now we start having tag pollution in the Hadoop questions where some questions are tagged with both where they should only have "hadoop".

Even their wikis are exactly identical to the letter.

Comment: Projects which are taken up by the folks at Apache tend to have "Apache" prefixed in their names.  The tags *should* be synonymous, but with `apache-hadoop` as the master to reflect the new correct name.

Comment: @Charles Really? I checked a few apache projects I know of, none of them are prefixed by "apache" : cassandra, hbase, zookeeper, mahout, activemq, tomcat, ... Given the fact that "hadoop" has been around so much longer than "apache-hadoop" which was done as a straight copy from "hadoop", I would argue that to be consistent, "hadoop" should be the master, and when people think about "hadoop" they don't necessarily think about "apache".

Comment: Since the project was taken over by Apache, the *official product name* is "[Apache™ Hadoop®](http://hadoop.apache.org/)".  Complete with the TM and (R).  While it's still known as just plain old regular Hadoop, that's effectively just an abbreviation of the official full-form name.  It's better to be explicit than implicit...  This is just my opinion of course, and you are free to ignore it.

Comment: @Charles Makes total sense and I do appreciate your feedback. I find it just a hassle if I had to write "apache" before these projects every single time, and it also makes it hard to search or tag because if you start with "apache" it just gives the whole list of apache projects in the dropdown and you have to find your way to your tag through countless other tags. Projects like "ant", "cassandra", "solr", "tomcat" are the masters against their "apache" synonyms, I couldn't honestly find a single tag who has the "apache" synonym as master with a non "apache" as synonym.